# In React Native I am using react-native-camera getting java.double error

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

This happens when i try to render below code after updating the state

```
        _map(videoRecords, ({ publicUrl, originalFileName, id }) => (
  <View key={id}>
    <Text
      style={{ color: 'white', cursor: 'pointer', fontSize: 14 }}
    >
      {originalFileName}
    </Text>
    <FontIcon
      name="delete"
      color="tint"
      size={15}
      style={{ marginTop: 3 }}
      onPress={() => {
        const data = [...videoRecords];
        const remData = _filter(data, ({ mediaId: media }) => media !==id);
        setVideoRecords([...remData]);
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

[image]

Attempt to invoke virtual method , java.lang.double

I have given the permission to acesss the camera and record also

java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by Timing
at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:67)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.TimingModule.access$000(TimingModule.java:22)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.TimingModule$BridgeTimerManager.callTimers(TimingModule.java:28)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.JavaTimerManager$TimerFrameCallback.doFrame(JavaTimerManager.java:84)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1299)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1309)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:923)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:847)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1283)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
2023-04-09 22:38:47.097 19130-19130 unknown:Re...JavaModule com.tekion.sales                     E  Unhandled SoftException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by Timing
at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:67)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.TimingModule.access$000(TimingModule.java:22)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.TimingModule$BridgeTimerManager.callTimers(TimingModule.java:28)
at com.facebook.react.modules.cor

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.